# Java FX - How to terminate a ScheduledService

Tags: javafx

I wrote a little code to download some files from internet..if user click on cancel button this must be stopped..i use the cancel() method for do it..but it didn't work.

```
ScheduledService<Object> service = new ScheduledService<Object>() {
            protected Task<Object> createTask() {
                return new Task<Object>() {
                    protected Object call() {
                        if (checkinternet()) {
                            downloadFiles();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                };
            }
        };
        service.start();
```

In buttons action event handler i called cancel method for stop service..
but it wasn't successful..

```
service.cancel();
```

How do i do that...

Comment: I had a similar problem too, with EJB timer service. Once a job is in a running state, calling cancel didn't abort it. The job only stops after the finishing it's current "work". I wonder what method could be used to abort!

Comment: did you try .setOnCancelled() listner..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way to cancel a task or service.

From the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm):

> **Cancelling the `Task`.**
>
> There is no reliable way in Java to stop a thread in process. However, the task must stop processing whenever `cancel` is called on the task. The task is supposed to check periodically during its work whether it was cancelled by using the `isCancelled` method within the body of the call method.

The example referenced in the above block looks like this:

```
Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
    @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {
        int iterations;
        for (iterations = 0; iterations < 100000; iterations++) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
               break;
            }
            System.out.println("Iteration " + iterations);
        }
        return iterations;
    }
};
```

So you will have to implement the cancel logic by yourself, unfortunately.